# Linear Programming change of right hand side

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

The question is the following:

Given a linear program: $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} c^Tx, Ax=b, x\ge 0$, where $x\ge 0$ means, that all components of $x$ have to be greater equal $0$. Further we know that this lp has a finite solution.

In my exercise I am supposed to prove that if I change the right hand-side, so if I leave all other things ($A$ and $c$) unchanged, but choose a new $b$, I also get either a finite solution or none.

Comment: You need to be more careful with your terminology.  A "finite solution" is very different from "finitely many solutions".  The first concerns the size of the components only, not how many solutions there are.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "change the right hand side"?

Comment: I have written it in the edit